# Displaying & Correctly

Tags: php

I have url links in a database like

```
( 50712&gift=pi )
```

but when I call the link it displays as

```
( 50712&amp;gift=pi )
```

now as there are hundreds of links how to I get it to display correctly

thanks in advance

Comment: call the link? in a database? can you clarify a bit more what you want to accomplish? and what you are doing exactly?

Comment: for example..

I input " This & That "  and if I look in that database thats how it is written

When I call it, it displays as  " This &amp; That  "
Where I need it to display  " This & That  "

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) on your link.

**EDIT:**

As said in the comments, don't forget to use `ENT_NOQUOTES` as quote_style, it will avoid security problems.

Comment: And open a potential security vulnerability. What if the url contains &quot; ?

Comment: It does in certain cases, but handled correctly you don't have to worry. For example with ENT_NOQUOTES

Comment: so as I display my link with    ". $row['link'] . "

how would I use it..

So rather a noob

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('arg_separator.output', '&');
```